# How to dynamically compile a component added to a template in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am building a blog with VueJS 2. Most of my articles are stored as Markdown files, but I want to me able to cover some more advanced topics, using features that Markdown doesn't cover. I am considering making these special posts VueJS components that would be used in a template as `<article-name>`, or `<special-article article-title="{{articleTitle}}">`. Pretty simple.

I have the component loaded already, so all I need to do is compile the template string into a real template. I might be thinking too much with my AngularJS background rather than with Vue.

I can't find any solid direction for dynamically adding a component to a template in VueJS.

Comment: do you need this? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components

Comment: @KresimirPendic yup! Those solutions were more complicated than what I needed, though. Check the other answers for the simpler solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can compile a template with [Vue.compile](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-compile). Just be aware it's not available in all builds. That's covered in the documentation.

Getting the data associated with it is a little more work.

```js
console.clear()

const articles = [
  {
    title: "Testing",
    articleTemplate: "<article-title></article-title>"
  },
  {
    title: "Testing 2",
    articleTemplate: "<special-article :article-title='title'></special-article>"
  },
]

Vue.component("article-title",{
  template: `<span>Article Title</span>`
})

Vue.component("special-article", {
  props:["articleTitle"],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h1>{{articleTitle}}</h1>
      <p>Some article text</p>
    </div>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{
    articles
  },
  computed:{
    compiledArticles() {
      return this.articles.map(a => {
        // compile the template
        let template = Vue.compile(a.articleTemplate)
        // build a component definition object using the compile template.
        // What the data function returns is up to you depending on where 
        // the data comes from.
        return Object.assign({}, template, {data(){return a}})
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.9/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <component v-for="article in compiledArticles" :is="article"></component>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! The `<component>` component was actually all that I needed for now. In the future, I'll load the list of special articles only when needed, but for now it is easy enough to bundle them with the rest of the site.

Comment: great, just one question, why the object assign ? cant u just return an object with the required properties ? (yes u can), ok, i see, this is to avoid using the spread operator :) it didn’t exist back then

Answer (score 2):

VueJS has a built-in component for this scenario:

`<component is="article-component-name"></component>`

Comment: Link to docs for those interested: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components