# Load Vue single-file component dynamically at runtime

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-dynamic-components

We've got a Vue app and would like to allow third parties to create plugins. We'd like the plugins to be built in the form of a Vue single-file component.

At runtime, the end user would select a plugin to add to the app. The app would fetch the plain-text .vue file, compile it on the fly, and display it in the app.

Vue supports [dynamic and async components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html), but these to be compiled into the app ahead of time. We'd like to do the same thing, except load the code on the fly.

How can I make this work?

Here's what I've got so far:

```
<template>
  <div>
    The component goes here:
    <component :is="pluginComponent"></component>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { parseComponent } from "vue-template-compiler";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      pluginComponent: null
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    // fetch code from some external source here
    let code = "<template><div>hello</div></template>";
    let comp = parseComponent(code);
    this.pluginComponent = comp;
  }
};
</script>
```

(I modified the build so the vue-template-compiler is present.)

The code above generates this error:

```
[Vue warn]: invalid template option:[object Object]
found in
---> <Anonymous>
       <Pages/plugin/PluginId.vue> at pages/plugin/_plugin_id.vue
         <Nuxt>
           <Layouts/default.vue> at layouts/default.vue
             <Root> instrument.js:110
    instrumentConsole instrument.js:110
    VueJS 15
TypeError: "vnode is null"
    VueJS 14
instrument.js:110
```

I'm guessing that whatever parseComponent() produces isn't what `<component>` is looking for.

Comment: Thihs should do what you want ... https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/distributed-vue-applications-loading-components-via-http/

Comment: @mark-hahn This is the answer. Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42020118/138579 *(disclaimer: author here)*

Answer (score 4):

> I'm guessing that whatever `parseComponent()` produces isn't what `<component>` is looking for

I'd say yes, as it doesn't seem to compile to any `render` functions.

As stated in the [docs](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/tree/dev/packages/vue-template-compiler#readme), `vue-template-compiler` is for runtime-compilation. And in most cases you should be using it with `vue-loader`.

> How can I make this work?

You might want to use [`Vue.compile`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-compile) as it allows you to compile template string into a `render` function; which you can then bind to an object for an async or dynamic component.

Do note, however, that this is **only available in the full build**, which is roughly 30% heavier-weight than the runtime-only build counterparts. Read more on [Runtime + Compiler vs. Runtime-only](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only).

With that in mind, since you didn't mention in the question, which bundler you are using, I'm going to assume Webpack with Vue-CLI, and here's how you would configure the `vue` alias (as a reference point when importing).

#### Verifying your set Vue "alias"

In your console (from the root of the project), run:

```
vue inspect resolve.alias.vue$
```

If that results in something along "vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js" (it should be, by default), then it's clear that we need to change this part.

#### Configuring it

Now, since the internal webpack config is maintained using [`webpack-chain`](https://github.com/neutrinojs/webpack-chain), we would configure/reset the alias like so:

```js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.resolve.alias
      .set('vue$', 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js')
  }
}
```

Check out the [explanation of different builds](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Explanation-of-Different-Builds).

#### Using it

And at this point, all you'd need to do is pass the "dynamic" template to the `compile` function, excluding the `<template>` tag though.

```js
import Vue from 'vue';

export default {
  mounted() {
    // fetch code from some external source here
    let code = '<div>hello</div>';
    let comp = Vue.compile(code);
    
    this.pluginComponent = comp;
  }
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    The component goes here:
    <component :is="pluginComponent"></component>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you. This works, but only for template code. How do I do a full single-file component, with script and style sections?

Comment: Unfortunately, `Vue.compile` is only meant for generating `render` functions for templates. Talking about the `<script>` part, you could try merging the content with this compiled template, which would require extra work. But see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47759562/3634538) for an example. As for the `<style>` part, I'm thinking of ["injecting" it on the `<head>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/524721/3634538). AFAIK, there isn't a full-blown solution for this yet.